# Changing globally manipulated variable being passed through onclick function

Tags: javascript, html, json, onclick, pugjs

I am having trouble changing a JSON object when using an onclick function on a table row in my .pug file.  My function is located in a .js file.

```
<th onclick="changeQuality(#{JSON.stringify(testData)}, 'Good')" class= "col-fixed-img"><img src="/images/Check.jpg"></th>
```

my function changeQuality() located in my .js file:

```
 function changeQuality(testData, id) {
  testData.newQuality = id;
}
```

The value is getting set properly within my changeQuality function in my .js file, however it doesn't change the value of testData in my .pug file.  How can I make it so that when this function is called it will update immediately the data found in my .pug file?

Comment: `onclick="changeQuality(#` That looks like invalid syntax. Also, it's much better practice to attach listeners properly with Javascript rather than with inline handlers

Comment: Sorry about that.  I'm using pugjs, but html in this specific part of my .pug file.

Comment: You need to pass an actual reference to `testData` into your function. By stringifying it, you are passing the function a new string so your function adds a `newQuality` property to the string, which is probably not what you want.